# Applescript to open javascript bookmark

Tags: applescript, bookmarks

i have the following javascript that searches the current site (very handy)

```
javascript:Qr=prompt('Search%20Site%20for','');if(Qr)location.href='http://www.google.com/search?&q=site:'+encodeURIComponent(window.location.hostname)+'+'+escape(Qr)
```

I am a launchbar user, but launchbar will not open this javascript bookmark.

Can i create an applescript that runs the javascript bookmark (in chrome, which is my default browser)

Have tried:-

```
tell application "Google Chrome"    
    execute javascript "javascript:Qr=prompt('Search%20Site%20for','');if(Qr)location.href='http://www.google.com/search?&q=site:'+encodeURIComponent(window.location.hostname)+'+'+escape(Qr"
end tell
```

but nothing happens...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three problems with the script you posted, and one of them may be just a problem that was caused when you pasted the code into your question.

Starting from the beginning: You need to tell Chrome where to do the JavaScript, like this:

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to tell active tab of front window to execute javascript "your script"
```

That will run the script in the current tab of the first window you opened (AFAIK, you can't yet get the active tab of the active window).

Next, you don't want that `javascript:` prefix; Chrome knows it's JavaScript.

Finally, you're missing a paren at the very end of your line. Again, I'm not sure if this is just a copy problem, but it's something to be aware of.

Making the above changes, I have this code:

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to tell active tab of front window to execute javascript "Qr=prompt('Search%20Site%20for','');if(Qr)location.href='http://www.google.com/search?&q=site:'+encodeURIComponent(window.location.hostname)+'+'+escape(Qr)"
```

...which works.

Comment: you absolute beauty!!! you wont believe how much i enjoy using this script, such a timesaver.

Comment: @rapscalli if this solved the problem, don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the check mark next to it. :)